# Is it possible to call an Oracle function from a SELECT statement with Pandas (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, oracle10g

Say I have a SELECT statement, which calls an Oracle function (in a package):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
  (col_1_A,
   col_2_A)
SELECT
  col_1_B,
  some_oracle_function(param1, param2)
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE col_1_B > 1
GROUP BY
  col_1_B,
  some_oracle_function(param1, param2)
;
```

This statement unsurprisingly works fine when running the statement as it is, from within Oracle Developer.

We are moving some operations to a micro service architecture, and we are trying to use Pandas to run similar statements. So instead of create a temporary table `TABLE_A`, we want to perform the operations in memory on data frames, before writing to a final table.

It doesn't seem like SQLAlchemy knows quite how what to do with the function call, so its just ignored. Is it possible? I suspect the same goes for Oracle builtin functions (`nvl`, `sum` etc.). It may not be the correct way to do this, if so, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know SQLAlchemy nor Pandas, but I suspect that what you claim is not true. If `some_stored_procedure` really is a "procedure", then it can't work. It *would work* if it were a **function** (not a procedure).

Comment: Fair point. I checked, it's actually a function in a package. I'll edit my question for clarity.